# Individually style each letter of a string

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I have a live counter on my website and I want it to look like this:**

> [image: Counter]

The counter is basically a short script which outputs a string consisting of multiple numbers. I would like to style this string like the numbers on the screenshot above, but I can't seem to find a way, which would allow me to do so.

I did some research and I found people who also wanted to style individual characters, but they wanted to do so with fixed ones, so they just used multiple spans which I of course can not do…

This is the HTML-Side of the Counter:

```
<span class="value_timer">00</span>
```

Does anyone have an idea on how I could do this?

Comment: You would have a separate script that splits your string and wraps each character in it's own span....there are many similar questions here for that.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```js
const target = document.querySelectorAll('span.value_timer')[0];

const val = target.textContent

const chars = val.split('');

target.innerHTML = chars.map(c => `<span class="digit">${c}</span>`).join('');
```

```css
span.digit {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 4em;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  margin: 2px;
 }
```

```html
<span class="value_timer">00</span>
```

Comment: Thank you! – I actually don't have any jQuery experience, but I will look into it now and implement this into my Website. :)

Comment: Dear @inorganik, I tried implementing this to my website, but it doesn't work. When I apply this script to some random text it does work, but not if I use it on my timer. – I'm sorry to bother you with this, but I'm still very new to JS and I would be very grateful if you could give me any sort of input on how I can make this work. I recreated the issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/Simon_R/5x16tzue/

Comment: @SimonR. here you go - https://jsfiddle.net/t3qyvbsx/ - the reason yours didn't work is because the selector took the first instance, see the zero at the end? `querySelectorAll('span.value_timer')[0]`. I just made the styling code into a function that accepts any html element in my fiddle.

Comment: Sorry I missed a small issue in there - updated version: https://jsfiddle.net/t3qyvbsx/2/

Comment: Thank you so much! ^^

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this without JavaScript might be to use a linear-gradient background.

```css
.value_timer {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Courier New", monospace; /* Must be a monospace font */
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #FFF;
  letter-spacing: .5em;
  text-indent: .2em;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) .2em, rgba(255,255,255,0) .2em), /* Hide extra BG caused by text-indent */
              linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 90%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 90%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  background-size: 100%, 1.1em;
}
```

```html
<span class="value_timer">123456789</span>
```

Comment: Hey, this is a really good idea, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.value_timer{
width:65px;
height:65px;
background:black;
color:white;
text-align:center;
justify-content:center;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in my situation. // I tried adding display:flex, but it didn't change anything…